# Google Spreadsheet IF and AND

Tags: formula, spreadsheet

im trying to find an easy formula to do the following:

```
=IF(AND(H6="OK";H7="OK";H8="OK";H9="OK";H10="OK";H11="OK";);"OK";"X")
```

This actually works. But I want to apply to a range of cells within a column (H6:H11) instead of having to create a rule for each and every one of them... But trying as a range:

```
=IF(AND(H6:H11="OK";);"OK";"X")
```

Does not work.
Any insights?
Thanks.

Comment: it was suggested automatically

Comment: @pnuts [excel]-tag: *Only for questions on programming against Excel objects or files...* google spreadsheets use excel-files... i'd say the tag is correct

Comment: I think the accepted answer provides the resolution to the tagging question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(AND(H6:H11="OK");"OK";"X"))
```

also works

arrayformulas work the same way they do in excel... they just need an `ArrayFormula()` around to work (will be automatically set when pressing Ctrl+Alt+Return like in excel)

Comment: Yes, Yes it does and I like yours better.

Answer (score 1):

In google sheets the formula is:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(SUM(IF(H6:H11="OK";1;0))=6;"OK";"X"))
```

in excel:

```
=IF(SUM(IF(H6:H11="OK";1;0))=6;"OK";"X")
```

And confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter

This basically counts the number of times the said range is = to the criteria and compares it to the number it should be.  So if the range is increased then increase the number 6 to accommodate.

Comment: there is no need for any sum... as array and(range=string) will be true if all values in range are the set string...

Comment: however... not using arrayformula you could use `=IF(COUNTIF(H6:H11;"<>""")=COUNTIF(H6:H11;"=OK");"OK";"X")`... fummy fact: `COUNTIF(H6:H11;"<>""")` will also count cells with `=""` while excel will not :P

Comment: @DirkReichel Yes but you can use `COUNTA` instead. `=IF(COUNTA(H6:H11)=COUNTIF(H6:H11,"OK"),"OK","X")`

Comment: @DirkReichel and the excel version of yours is `=IF(COUNTIF(H6:H11;"<>")=COUNTIF(H6:H11;"=OK");"OK";"X")`

Comment: `COUNTIF(H6:H11;"<>")` will not count empty cells in excel (counta also will wont do)... you need to add the count of empty cells to make it work ;)

Comment: @DirkReichel Your technically right.`COUNTIF(H6:H11;"<>")` will count all non empty cells in the range, while `COUNTIF(H6:H11;"=")` will count all empty cells in range.

Comment: but unfortunately `COUNTIF(H6:H11;"=")` wont count cells containing something... but if you are able to find a way to count ALL cells in a range with one function without VBA that would solve the problem :)

Comment: @DirkReichel so the true non array formula should be `=IF(COUNTIF(H6:H11,"<>")+COUNTIF(H6:H11,"=")=COUNTIF(H6:H11,"=OK"),"OK","X")` for excel.  Yes you can use `CountA() + CountBlank()` also.  Sorry my local settings are for `,` instead of `;`